# Laravel Rotating Eloquent Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, replication

I have a Laravel Project where I aggregate data on each 30m from different REST APIs and on the flow I build up the relational model based on the fetched Data. Before fetching the Data I clean up the main table and the related tables too. Sometimes this can take long till data is getting repopulated, up to 1-2m which would mean that I have a gap on production.

I'm searching for a workaround to keep the previously populated data live till the new data is getting aggregated and saved in the database.

Are there any good practices for this kind of Logic? Or the the idea behind is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put column like `revision` and instead of removing everything from tables you create new revision? Then app can display always latest revision and you can delete data after import is finished or at any time you want because when you finish import you will have new revision so app will automatically display newest revision data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Feedback, can you post a snippet for explanatory purpose to have an idea about `revisions`.